# How can we handle result of HttpResponse in android?

Tags: android, httpresponse

I am working on android. i am sending username and password using HttpPost and getting userid.

This is my code for my operation:

```
HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.214/sample/dologin.php id="+strUID+ "&password="+strPass);

HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);

if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    String userID = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
    Log.v("Login response", "" + userID);
}
```

This is my output in DDMS

```
Login response(686): ([{"id":"5"}]);
```

But I need 5 as a result. So I can use this result in my next operations. Please tell me what should I do to extract 5 from the string ([{"id":"5"}]);

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON below is simple code..

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(userID);
String s = sb.substring(sb.indexOf("["),sb.lastIndexOf("]")+1);
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(s);
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo = (ja.getJSONObject(0));
String id = jo.getString("id");
```

Now you can use id variable..

Answer (score 2):

```
public void postData(String strUID,String strPass) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.214/sample/dologin.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",strUID ));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",strPass ));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        JSONObject response=new JSONObject(responseBody);

        response.get('id');
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your help will be meaningful for me. but your this line of code is creating the error  response.get('id');  this is the error "invalid character constant". so please suggest me what should i do to resolve this error ?

Comment: before response.get('id'); make repsone= response.getJSONObject(0);

Answer (score 1):

I seems like your answer is packed into an JSONObject.
To handle this response just use the org.json package and parse your answer into a json.
The shortest way to extract the answer is:

```
JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(userID);
String myID = myJson.get("id");
// or myJson.getString("id");
```

also i recomand not to use the POST method but the GET method as you are not calling a ressource via GET.